# How to fix 'no library called "cairo" was found' when importing cairocffi?

Tags: python, windows, cairo

I was trying to import cariocffi, but when I tried, it gave me this problem:

```
>>>import cairocffi as cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 44, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'
```

Python version: 3.11
cairocffi version (from pip freeze): cairocffi==1.6.1

I did not find any solution for the problem.

Comment: From https://doc.courtbouillon.org/cairocffi/stable/overview.html#installing-cairocffi: "*cairocffi will dynamically load cairo as a shared library at this point. If it fails to find it, you will see an exception like this:

OSError: library not found: 'cairo'

Make sure cairo is correctly installed and available through your system’s usual mechanisms.*"

Comment: I don't use or have a WIndows machine, so I can't verify, but there's a section on the cairocffi docs for [Installing cairo on Windows](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/cairocffi/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows): "*cairocffi needs a libcairo-2.dll file in a directory that is listed in the PATH environment variable. [Alexander Shaduri’s GTK+ installer works](http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Main/Downloads). (Make sure to leave the Set up PATH environment variable checkbox checked.)* (looks like those gtk installers also include cairo)